# How to use jQuery on widget admin page

Tags: widgets

I have a lengthy form config for my widget so I thought about using radio buttons to hide and show the relevant input fields instead of having them all after each other. But it doesn't seem to work. I suppose it is because the form is loaded with ajax? Is there a way to get it to work?

Take a look at the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JmVL3/

Comment: What does your browser's debugger say?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. Neither firebug or chrome gives any errors. I've just noticed that it works fine to alert a message instead of hiding/showing the input field when clicking the radio buttons.

Comment: It also works everywhere else on the admin page. Just not inside the widget settings. I tried to use .ajaxsucces() around the code but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Another thing. It also works if i enable accessibility mode.

Comment: @toscho, I can reproduce the issue, it is possible to see the manipulations happening in the Html code (i.e.: `$("#field2").css('display','block');`), but the widget form shows no change...

Comment: could you pastebin the whole widget code please?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, which I resolved by changing all my IDs to classes. Remember that widgets can be used multiple times on page, so specifying an ID anywhere increases the likelihood that you'll have ID duplication (Which will in turn cause jQuery to have a fit).